# Why doesn't Entity Framework throw an exception here?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Look at this code:

```
Blog blog = new Blog { Url = "http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet" };
blog.Posts.Add(
     new Post { Title = "Hello World", Content = "I wrote an app using EF Core!" });

db.Add(blog);
db.SaveChanges();

// db.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("Delete from Blogs"); --> throw exception for Foreign key
//db.Remove(blog); // --> works and doesn't throw exception

db.SaveChanges();
```

I don't understand why when deleting a blog who contain a post, we have an exception for foreign key (it is normal because I removed the cascade option). But when I do `db.Remove(blog)`, no exception is thrown, and the blog is deleted from the database...

EDIT :

I will be more explicit:

I intentionally changed the delete behavior from `onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade` to `onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict`, that's why i have a foreign key exception if i try to delete the blog with the sql command.

Other thing, i delete all the blogs to make the things simple, but in the database i just have added only one blog, specifiying the id doesn't change anything.

Comment: EF will write the necessary commands to cascade the deletes from child tables also, preventing a FK error

Comment: Because you've configured your relationship to cascade delete, and EF is doing that for you client side?

Comment: Turn on logging of the SQL commands executed. You'll see pretty quickly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a read of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.deletebehavior?view=efcore-5.0

There are various ways you can tell EF to behave when you remove a parent entity. If you're not seeing the database throw an error when you remove a parent then EF is doing some fix up in the background - either successfully deleting all the children it knows about first, or breaking the relationship by setting the foreign key column of the child to null (orphaning) first, before removing the parent

If you've never specifically set any behavior then what EF is doing will depend on whether Post.BlogId is nullable or not. If it's not, then the posts will be being deleted. If it is then they'll be being set to have a null BlogId.

You can show the SQLs being executed (always a handy debug tool) if you find the `UseSqlServer` call in your startup config and chain something like a call to `.LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information)` onto it

Comment: I think you are right, but one thing is strange, in the link you shared, it is written : "If a property cannot be set to null because it is not a nullable type, then an exception will be thrown when SaveChanges() is called. " And the Post.BlogId is not nullable, but instead of throwing the error, it remove it too.

Comment: With Restrict active, if Posts.BlogId (the child end of the relationship) is not nullable, an exception should occur when Remove is called; EF will complain it cannot sever the relationship: *System.InvalidOperationException: 'The association between entity types 'Customer' and 'Order' has been severed, but the relationship is either marked as required or is implicitly required because the foreign key is not nullable. If the dependent/child entity should be deleted when a required relationship is severed, configure the relationship to use cascade deletes*

Comment: If it *is* nullable then it will be set locally to be `null`, but this might cause a failure to save if the BlogId column in the DB does not allow nulls (*SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'BlogId'*,

Comment: If the property is nullable and the column is nullable, then removing a Blog should cut the tie to Posts; that Post will be orphaned - it will still exist in the Posts table, with NULL in its BlogId

Comment: Object lesson: for least surprises ensure your DB and your EF models agree on things like nullability, and cascading of X

Comment: The BlogId is NOT nullable ("BlogId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_Posts_Blogs_BlogId" FOREIGN KEY ("BlogId") REFERENCES "Blogs" ("BlogId") ON DELETE RESTRICT) but the blog and the post are both deleted...

Comment: Which DB is this? I've been advising based on SQLS but it doesn't have ON DELETE RESTRICT.. I wonder if behavior is different with a different provider, but the behavior you describe sounds like Client/Cascade

Comment: I am using sqlite, but I have noticed something, if i read the blog entity without including the post in the entity object, the remove will throw an error, but if i read the blog entity including the posts list, then everything is removed

Comment: You perhaps skipped the significance of the initial words *"For entities being tracked by the DbContext"* in MSDN?

Comment: I understand that, but it seems the behavior change if we truck only the blog or the blog with the sub posts. But thank you for the link, now I realize that entity framework is able to do many things even if it is only asked to delete an element when entities being tracked by the DbContext

Comment: Yes, as I understand it an EF context will take action only on things it knows about (has seen be downloaded before) - if you don't include the Posts then I'd expect a database error trying to save the Blog; EF thinks there are no posts because none were ever downlaoded, so it just issues a command to delete the Blog. The FK in the DB might prevent that, and SaveChanges gives an error. If EF *does* know about the Posts then it may do something to them; setnull/delete according to their nullability and the OnDeleteBehavior, which might mean it takes more action on the DB end.. If you think..

Comment: ..there's a mismatch between the behavior you see and the behavior the docs say there should be then we can test it and report an issue in the docs if they seem to be wrong. Would beed a full repro: what are the exact wntities, including type and nullability of navigation properties, what are the DB side FK and nullability settings, and what code do we do to cause the error..

Answer (score 0):

you have to add Id to your sql script. As it is now you are deleting all blogs, not just a new one. But some posts can have BlogId from another posts and you can not delete them, before you assign a foreign key to null or if it is  not possible delete all the posts before.

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("Delete from Blogs where BlogId="+blog.BlogId.ToString());
```

Comment: That's SQL injection right there: should be `db.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("Delete from Blogs where BlogId = {0};", blog.BlogId);`

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you, but sql injection can only be from a user input control data. I am sorry but where you can see an user input  control data here? Even a BlogId is an integer. I am not even talking that there is no difference between your and my code. it is just a different style, but it will create the same string.

Comment: Never encourage raw sql like this. Particularly in an answer. *Always* bind parameters, it helps with query performance anyway. BTW It doesn't create the same string, it binds the parameter.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I am agree with you completely, but it is not my question and not my code, otherwise I could put a lot of validations, but it is out of the scope ot the question. The error is not because there is no a parameter.  As I understand author is goint to use only EF code, with sql strings. This is just an example. And my task is just to give a hint. I am not  going to spend my time writing the tonns of code for OP. I am not a free coder here and nobody pays me for this.

Comment: How do you know OP's primary key is an `int`, there is no mention of it? Even if it is, as mentioned it's bad practice, and there is also the performance aspect. You're right there is no point putting in heavy validation and error-handling in a one-liner, but my code is actually *shorter* than yours. The string I gave uses proper parameterization, see [the actual documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#passing-parameters) for how it's supposed to be used, in particular *"Always use parameterization for raw SQL queries..."*

Comment: If this was `ExecuteSqlInterpolated($"... WHERE id = {blog.Id}")` no one would have batted an eyelid..

Comment: Minor point; this doesn't actually answer the question being asked - it's not "how do I make this throw?" It's "why doesn't it throw?" - providing code that would make it throw doesn't really address that

Comment: @CaiusJard I am sorry for a dispute, but It seems to me that here some people know only 3 words - json, linq and sql script injection. It makes me to go  berserc already. I think it is time for them to learn one new word at least.

Comment: I made and Edit to explain that there was only the blog I added so specifying the id doesn't change anything

Comment: *some people know only 3 words* - LOL'd at this.. Though I'm pleased at least that people jump on SQL injection fairly reliably - what makes me berserk is that the SQL injection questions keep coming? What crap tutorials out there are teaching people to do it? Or is it really the case that every newbie that turns up with some injection prone SQL, did it because they imagined that's how it should be done.. How can we turn that off at source?! Or are we doomed to suffer it forever? Rewrite the DB to not accept constants in an SQL! Parameterize *everything*. Bah :D

Comment: @CaiusJard Sometimes I don' t want to answer a question where there is an sql string because I am afraid to throw up if I hear about  an sql injection again.

Comment: Yeah, it gets pretty tedious answering every carp question not only to fix their "put the apostrophe in the wrong place" issue but also to give a lecture on parameters and SQL injection, and fix their code so it isn't. Believe it or not I post nearly exclusively from a cellphone on the mobile site and pecking the params lecture/fix out every time gets boring, then there's the AddWithValue debate.. I'd prefer to just have "contains serious security risk" as a close vote reason, with some advice for them on how to remedy it (in the comments) - and reopen the question when theyve sorted it out

Comment: @CaiusJard AddWithValue debate LOL. Yes, this is one more word that a couple of people heard. My opinion is  - let anybody decide what to use or not to use.

Comment: But sadly, what other option do we have? Even letting one person get away with it one time might lead to a "well a person on the internet implied it's OK to write SQL like this" and then lead to something like the VTech hack, where some dumbwit left an SQL Injection hole open that caused the exposure of data of 6.5 million children. People copy paste off SO and dont think about it all the time, so we have to jump on it and tell people they're running a risk - it might not always be grandma's record collection database theyre working on! :/